# Choosing specific digits of values from two datasets

Tags: r, subset

I'm relatively new to R. I'm looking for a way to choose a specific value of pfaf from two datasets of points from sites, based on some conditions.
data2 is a subset of data1. But I've only included one value that match.

data1:

```
site      id    strahler      pfaf
1331879 1232926 4             4359
1331341 1232926 2             816
1330121 1232926 1             45 
1331842 1232926 3             4
1331841 1232926 2             552
1329931 1206877 3             413
1329614 1206877 2             47
1329591 1206877 1             8179
1329517 1206877 1             4463
1331411 1554221 1             912
1331364 1554221 1             92
1329694 1554221 2             9113
1331486 1554221 3             8
```

I need to get the series (several) of sites which corresponds to a series of pfaf numbers from data1. These pfaf numbers need to follow these rules.

1) The first n digits of data2$pfaf matches exactly to data1$pfaf, where n ≥ 0, AND

2) The remaining digits of data2$pfaf are less than and/or equal to the remaining digits of data1$pfaf

At the same time, the id of data2$pfaf and data1$pfaf need to be the same for them to be compared at all. AND the strahler of sites have to be less than or equal to the strahler of points.

data2:

```
points  id      strahler    pfaf
1331485 1206877 3           821
1329690 1206877 2           47
1329598 1232926 4           46
1329936 1554221 1           962
```

The correct output would be:

```
points  pfaf_of_site    site
1331485 816, 8179       1329614, 1329591
1329690 4463            1329517
1329598 4359, 45, 4     1331879, 1330121, 1331842
1329936 912, 92         1331411, 1331364
```

Thanks a tonne for the help if someone can do this.

Comment: Please (1) give a small example of `data2$PFAFFSTETTER` (3 rows is plenty). (2) Tell us more about `n`... Does `n` have a specific value? Or do you want to maximize `n`? Or you want to run for different values of `n`? (3) Show your expected output based on the sample inputs you provided.

Comment: The output I'd want all the WSO1_ID with PFAFFSTETTER numbers from data2, which corresponds to the PFAFFSTETTER numbers of WSO1_IDs in data1, since data2 is the complete dataset.

All the search need to be based on the same WSO_ID.

n is the first number of any PFAFFSTETTER number. So if it is 821, then I need all numbers like 834, 86611, 822. Is this a good enough example?

data2 has the same layout. It just has more variety of WSO_ID, and even more of WSO1_ID. 

For more context, it's a hydrological system values.

Comment: Yeah, that's good. I've cut down your example data so they are more approachable and easier to understand. I'm surprised/confused that `data2$PFAFSTETTE` is printed with decimals -- should they be integers? Do decimals matter?

Comment: I'm also still confused about the output. Now that we have a nice small example (feel free to cut even more rows!), can you give the expected output? For example, the first row of `data2` has a 1, and no rows of `data1` start with 1, so I think there is no match. Second row, `data2` is 45. If we take `n = 1`, I think that should match `46`, `47`, and `48` in `data1` because 4 == 4 and 5 < 6, 7, 8. Does it also match `4463`, because `5 < 463`? Or does it not match because `5 > 4`? If there was a `461`, would that match because `5 < 6`, or would it not match because `5 > 1`?

Comment: And lastly, just to clarify, for the purposes of this question, `OBJECTID`, `WSO_ID, and `STRAHLER` *do not matter at all*, correct? The only columns that you mention are `PFAFFSTETTER` and `WSO1_ID`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Those datasets help, but I think something is still missing.  For this example to work, shouldn't there be some values in `data1$WSO1_ID` that are also in ``data2$WSO1_ID`?  Maybe present a simpler, more artificial example with on the necessary elements for your question.  perhaps fewer rows.  And certainly fewer columns, since I think each dataset requires only two columns for your question.

Comment: @Gregor OUH! I understand your problem now. Thank you so much for being patient and explaining what you needed. I hope your're still gonna see this.
The decimals were a mistake. There aren't decimals.
I'm going to update it to an artificial dataset now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following function is what you want? Untested, since there is no `data2` example.

```
funMatch <- function(X, Y, n = 1){
  x <- as.character(X[['PFAFSTETTER']])
  x.n <- substr(x, 1, n)
  x.remaining <- substring(x, n + 1)
  y <- as.character(Y[['PFAFSTETTER']])
  y.n <- substr(y, 1, n)
  y.remaining <- substring(y, n + 1)
  i <- which(y.n %in% x.n & length(y.remaining) < length(x.remaining))
  Y[['WSO1_ID']][i]
}

funMatch(data1, data2, n = 1)
funMatch(data1, data2, n = 2)
```